# ContentDispositionHeaderValueIdentityExtensions.IsFileDisposition thows ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null Parameter name: header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a legacy .Net Framework client with lots of installs that can't be changed. I need to handle the http post requests it uses to upload files to the server.

Previously we could use HttpContext.Request.Files. But as we are using dotnet core now, we have to use HttpContext.Request.Form.Files. Which is throwing an excaption

"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: header" the stack trace is as follows

> at
>   Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValueIdentityExtensions.IsFileDisposition(ContentDispositionHeaderValue
>   header) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.InnerReadFormAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm() at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Form()

Looking at the source for asp dotnet core on github, I can see the exact issue [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Http/Headers/src/ContentDispositionHeaderValueIdentityExtensions.cs) on line 26.

```
return header.DispositionType.Equals("form-data")
                && (!StringSegment.IsNullOrEmpty(header.FileName) || !StringSegment.IsNullOrEmpty(header.FileNameStar));
```

I assumed that this was an issue with the client adding that header information to the files and not the request itself, but when I added a bit of middleware (below) to add that header to my request, the HttpContext.Request.Form still throws the exception. I don't know if this exception is being thrown upon creation, or if I am not setting the header correctly, or if this is a bug in dotnet core. There have been open issues on github to improve the error message, but nothing suggests that their code is the issue.

I want to just 'repair' the headers as I know that calls to this endpoint will always be multipart form data, ideally using middleware so the controller doesn't have to deal with it.

Middleware:

```
public class FormDataHeaderRepair
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public FormDataHeaderRepair(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var headers = context.Request.Headers;
        if (context.Request.Path.ToString().Equals("/api/MyController/Queue", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (context.Request.Headers["Content-Disposition"].Count == 0)
            {
               var cv = new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
               cv.FileName = "request.xml";
               var stringVersion = cv.ToString();
               context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.ContentDisposition] = stringVersion;
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

EDIT/UPDATE: Adding this code to my controller, returns 'true' for 'theResult' which makes me think that there is some other cached request/headers collection that ContentDispositionHeaderValueIdentityExtensions is using, as this is the exact evaluation code that they are using... either that or they are retrieving the header differently than this.

```
var header = HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().ContentDisposition;
var theResult = header.DispositionType.Equals("form-data") && (!StringSegment.IsNullOrEmpty(header.FileName) || !StringSegment.IsNullOrEmpty(header.FileNameStar));
```

Comment: Did you add the middleware as first middleware or at least before `app.UseMvc`? Otherwise it might manipulate the headers too late.

Comment: I think I added it at the end! Thanks, I hadn't thought about that at all. Will try and report back. EDIT: It was before MVC already. Damnit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with the request being sent to us being manually built, and not using any libraries (as it was developed in a time when it was apparently a nightmare to post multiple files like this)

If you read the spec for form based file submission [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867) you will see that you have a boundary (a string of chars you define as a separator between your two files binary data in the upload) which you also add to the end of the request to show that your last file has ended completely.

On the last/final boundary, you must terminate it with a trailing "--" after the boundary to show that this is the end of the upload. Our client code was not adding this final set of dashes. This was apparently handled in IIS/Full .Net Framework on the legacy server we were uploading to, it must have either silently errored or just assumed there were no more files and allowed the request through as valid. Using asp dotnet core, this was not the case, and the request was failing when trying to be processed.

The fix was indeed to add a piece of middleware to the app, ensuring to add it to the app setup before MVC is added.

```
app.RepairMissingFormDataHeaders();
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Basically the middleware reads the last few bytes of our request, and if it doesn't match the 'expected' bytes it creates a new byte array in memory and adds them in place. There are other checks in the middle ware as only one client hits this endpoint so we have it restricted on `context.Request.Path` to reduce the amount of times this is run

```
//Get a flipped version of what the final bytes should be
var endingBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("--\r\n").Reverse().ToArray();
var requiresRepair = false;

var last4Bytes = new byte[4];
//Check if the final bites line up
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    last4Bytes[i] = bytes[bytes.Length - (i + 1)];
}

var lastBytesAsString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(last4Bytes);
Logger.LogInformation($"MIDDLEWARE: Last 4 bytes {lastBytesAsString}");

//Check if the final bites line up
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (bytes[bytes.Length - (i + 1)] != endingBytes[i])
    {
        requiresRepair = true;
        break;
    }
}
```